# Analysis with respect to other elements

Tags: transitivity

I have a few ridge lines oriented in different directions. So, I want to check the orthogonality and parallelism of a ridge with respect to other ridges. I am struggling to figure out how to write this as I am unsure where ***each other*** should be placed. Here are my tries:

> 1. It depends on how ridges deviate from the orthogonality and
>      parallelism **of each other**.
> 2. It depends on how ridges deviate **each other** by the relative
>      orthogonality and parallelism.

Any assistance, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Deviate* is normally an intransitive verb, typically used with the preposition *from*; your second sentence is grammatically incorrect.  That said, the style in your first sentence is a bit awkward and ambiguous, even though grammatically it's okay.

I suggest these constructions:

> It depends on how ridges deviate **from each other's** orthogonality and parallelism.
>
> It depends on how ridges deviate **from each other** by **their** relative orthogonality and parallelism.

The first emphasizes that the metrics are different, while the second emphasizes that the ridges are going in divergent directions.